# How to check if string exists within a string?

Tags: rust

Lets say I have the string `"My name is Henricksen"` how do check if `"Henricksen"` name exists in the string?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.contains

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"My name is Henricksen".contains("Henricksen")
```